# How to filter specific rows from dataframe using multiple conditions?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, filter

im having trouble removing/filtering rows based on multiple conditions.

My data looks like this:

```
      time              media id    od  gfp
37    0.24    IO+Glc+CasA_gfp  1  0.00   81
38    0.24    IO+Glc+CasA_gfp  2 -0.07  -19
39    0.24    IO+Glc+CasA_gfp  3  0.02  -95
43    0.24 IO+Glc+CasA+Fe_gfp  1  0.01  123
44    0.24 IO+Glc+CasA+Fe_gfp  2  0.01  -17
45    0.24 IO+Glc+CasA+Fe_gfp  3  0.02  -40
85    0.72    IO+Glc+CasA_gfp  1 -0.02  128
86    0.72    IO+Glc+CasA_gfp  2 -0.01  -20
87    0.72    IO+Glc+CasA_gfp  3  0.01  -77
91    0.72 IO+Glc+CasA+Fe_gfp  1  0.14   15
92    0.72 IO+Glc+CasA+Fe_gfp  2  0.11  -12
93    0.72 IO+Glc+CasA+Fe_gfp  3  0.02   15
```

When plotting a specific graph i would like to filter all "IO+Glc+CasA+Fe_gfp" with id=1 and 2, but still keep everything else in the data. I have tried to use the filtering function but without luck, most likely because im using the function incorrectly.

I hope anyone can help, thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)
quux %>%
  filter(id %in% 1:2 | media != "IO+Glc+CasA+Fe_gfp")
#    time              media id    od gfp
# 37 0.24    IO+Glc+CasA_gfp  1  0.00  81
# 38 0.24    IO+Glc+CasA_gfp  2 -0.07 -19
# 39 0.24    IO+Glc+CasA_gfp  3  0.02 -95
# 43 0.24 IO+Glc+CasA+Fe_gfp  1  0.01 123
# 44 0.24 IO+Glc+CasA+Fe_gfp  2  0.01 -17
# 85 0.72    IO+Glc+CasA_gfp  1 -0.02 128
# 86 0.72    IO+Glc+CasA_gfp  2 -0.01 -20
# 87 0.72    IO+Glc+CasA_gfp  3  0.01 -77
# 91 0.72 IO+Glc+CasA+Fe_gfp  1  0.14  15
# 92 0.72 IO+Glc+CasA+Fe_gfp  2  0.11 -12
```

Rationale:

- `id %in% 1:2` will match against every `media`, true for only those two IDs; *however*
- `media != ".."`, will return `TRUE` for anything that's not "the one", so all of the non-`"IO+Glc+..."` IDs will be passed as well.

---

Data

```r
quux <- structure(list(time = c(0.24, 0.24, 0.24, 0.24, 0.24, 0.24, 0.72, 0.72, 0.72, 0.72, 0.72, 0.72), media = c("IO+Glc+CasA_gfp", "IO+Glc+CasA_gfp", "IO+Glc+CasA_gfp", "IO+Glc+CasA+Fe_gfp", "IO+Glc+CasA+Fe_gfp", "IO+Glc+CasA+Fe_gfp", "IO+Glc+CasA_gfp", "IO+Glc+CasA_gfp", "IO+Glc+CasA_gfp", "IO+Glc+CasA+Fe_gfp", "IO+Glc+CasA+Fe_gfp", "IO+Glc+CasA+Fe_gfp"), id = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), od = c(0, -0.07, 0.02, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, -0.02, -0.01, 0.01, 0.14, 0.11, 0.02), gfp = c(81L,  -19L, -95L, 123L, -17L, -40L, 128L, -20L, -77L, 15L, -12L, 15L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("37", "38", "39", "43", "44", "45", "85", "86", "87", "91", "92", "93"))
```